# Find a conformal map from semi-disc onto unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

This comes straight from Conway's Complex Analysis, VII.4, exercise 4.

> Find an analytic function $f$ which maps $G:=$ {${z: |z| < 1, Re(z) > 0}$} onto $B(0; 1)$ in a one-one fashion.

$B(0;1)$ is the open unit disc.

My first intuition was to use $z^2$, which does the job splendidly, except for the segment $(-1,0] \subset B(0;1)$.  Under $z^2$, the pre-image for this segment is the segment $[-i,i]$, which is not in $G$.

My next thought is to modify $z^2$, something like $a(z-h)^2+k$.  I've yet to work out the details, but my gut tells me this isn't the right idea.

I've been teaching myself conformal maps in preparation for a qualifying exam.  So, if there's a shockingly basic, obvious solution... please patronize me.

Comment: One thought (which I mostly pose from intuition) is seek a conformal map which maps $G$ to the right half-plane; from there it's not hard to map the right-half plane to $B(0;1)$ by a rotation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following trick works for any region bounded by two circular arcs (or a circular arc and a line).

Find the points of intersection of the arc and the line. (Here, they're $i$ and $-i$.) Now pick a Mobius transformation that takes one of those points to $0$ and the other to $\infty$; here $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ works. Then the arc and the line go to two rays (because a Mobius transformation sends circles in $S^2$ to circles in $S^2$, and the only circles in $S^2$ that goes through both $0$ and $\infty$ is a line in $\Bbb C$), both starting at $0$ and going off the $\infty$. Your domain maps to the region bounded by these two rays.

Let's compute the rays. It suffices to find where a single point on each arc maps; if $z_0$ is on the arc, the ray will be $\{f(z_0)t : 0 \leq t < \infty\}$. I say we pick $0$ to be our point of choice on $Re(z) = 0$ and $1$ to be the point of choice for the circular arc. These are mapped to $-1$ and $-I$ respectively; so our two arcs are the negative real axis and the negative imaginary axis. I'd like the "lower" arc to be the positive real axis, so let's multiply by $-1$ to do this.

So we have a conformal map from your half-disc to the upper-right quadrant given by $z \mapsto -\frac{z-i}{z+i}$. The upper half-plane is nicer, so let's map to that by squaring; now we have a map to the upper half plane given by $z \mapsto \frac{(z-i)^2}{(z+i)^2}$. (For other regions bounded by rays that make different angles, you get to the upper half plane by a $z \mapsto z^\beta$ for the appropriate $\beta$.)

Now there's a standard map from the upper half plane to the unit disc given by $z \mapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i}$. Composing this with our last map gives us a map from the semi-disc to the unit disc, given by $$z \mapsto -i\frac{z^2+2z-1}{z^2-2z-1}.$$

Comment: This is more insightful. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: For fun, I added the images of your mappings as a community wiki answer. Enjoy!

Comment: @ChristianRemling I appreciate the compliment!

Comment: It might be worth noting that, even before computing the two rays (the negative real and imaginary axes), you knew that they had to be perpendicular, because conformal maps preserve angles. So you already know that the next step should be squaring and that it would produce a half-plane. The details of the rays and the half-plane are needed only at the very end, when you map the half-plane to the disk.

Comment: @AndreasBlass That's definitely worth noting - thanks for commenting.

Comment: Thank you all!  This is exactly what I needed-- a general framework and a thorough explanation.

Comment: Mike, I understand that the image of $\text{Re}=0$ under your original map is a ray containing $0,\infty$, but how do you know that the ray starts at $0$? More generally, how do you know the rays are of the form $\lbrace f(z_0)t: 0\le t < \infty \rbrace$?

Comment: Under Mobius transforms, circles map to circles (in $S^2$; so either a circle or a line); they'll be viewed as a line in the plane iff one of the points in the circle is $\infty$. It is here. Then the endpoints of our arc map to endpoints of the new arc (for topological reasons, if you want). The rest follows from the fact that $0,\infty$ are the endpoints of the ray.

Comment: @user98602 What do you do if you have to calculate the arc values? (say the two arcs come from two circles intersecting). How do I then tell where the ray lands? I mean in this case, we were lucky to be able to pick 0 and 1 but what about a case where that is not possible?

Comment: Don't we have to be careful to check that $z \mapsto - \frac{z - i}{z + i}$ maps the semidisk to the upper-right quadrant, and not to the other three quadrants? Since the Riemann sphere doesn't have a Jordan Curve-esque distinction between interior and exterior of the loop made by these two rays, we only know so far that the image of $g$ is enclosed by the positive real and positive imaginary axes, but not *which* region with that boundary it maps to.

Comment: @AJY Conformal mappings preserve angles, and that include their orientation. The Jacobian is $|f'|^2>0$. Therefore, if one travels a curve and the region lies on one side, then the image lies on the same side of the image of the curve. If we were traveling from $i$ to $-i$ along the imaginary axis and the region was on the left, then in the image the region is on the left as we move from $0$ to $\infty$ along the positive real axis.

Answer (score 31):

As a supplement to the fine answers provided, here are the pictures of the conformal maps themselves:

[image]

We start with the right half of the unit disk, map it to the upper right quadrant, square this to the upper half-plane, and finally rotate onto the unit disk.

---

Per requests for code - the basic pattern to generate the image of a polar region $a\leq r \leq b$ and $\alpha \leq \theta \leq \beta$ under a function $f$ in Mathematica is:

```
ParametricPlot[{Re[f[r*Exp[I*theta]]], Im[f[r*Exp[I*theta]]]},
  {r, a, b}, {theta, alpha, beta}, Mesh -> True]
```

The pictures above may be generated with the following code block:

```
phi1[z_] = -(z - I)/(z + I);
f[z_] = z^2;
phi2[z_] = (z - I)/(z + I);
nestedFunctions = 
  Composition @@@ Table[Take[{phi2, f, phi1}, -k], {k, 0, 3}];
pics = Table[
  ParametricPlot[{Re[g[r*Exp[I*theta]]], Im[g[r*Exp[I*theta]]]},
      {r, 0, 1}, {theta, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, 
      Mesh -> True, PlotRange -> 2, ImageSize -> 360],
    {g, nestedFunctions}];
Grid[Partition[pics, 2]]
```

You can find a lot more information on visualizing complex function with Mathematica [in this notebook](https://marksmath.org/classes/Fall2018Complex/demos/VisualizingComplexFunctions.nb).

Comment: It appears I can only choose one answer, but I think these images are just as essential to the solution as the explanation.  With what program did you generate them?

Comment: It's from Mathematica. I'll incorporate the code for them when I get the chance. (Also, I should note that this really _isn't_ a proper answer since I didn't remember the proper conformal maps until I saw the other answers. Hence why I did this as a community wiki answer.)

Comment: As a rookie mathematica user I would find it usefully to see the code for these types of mappings.

Comment: I wonder if you can still recall the code :)

Comment: @snulty Code has been posted, if you are still interested.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yeah that’s cool, I had forgotten about that :) thanks!