# Biholomorphic functions on unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Is it possible to classify all biholomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{D}\backslash[-1,0]\to\mathbb D$ where $\mathbb D$ is the unit disk?

My repertoire of tools is very limited in this regard, especially since $\mathbb{D}\backslash[-1,0]$ is not a connected space, so Riemanns mapping theorem doesn't guarantee that there is one. However, I know that the automorphism group $Aut(\mathbb D)$ contains only elements of the form $\displaystyle f(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-a}{\bar az-1}$. How do I manipulate this information to get the desired solution?

Comment: $\mathbb{D}\setminus[-1,0]$ is connected (even simply-connected), $\mathbb{D}\setminus[-1,1]$ would be disconnected though.

Comment: Oh wow, don't know how I could have misread the 0 for a 1. So basically I need to restrict the functions $f$ given above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to find a biholomorphic conformal mapping $g$ between $\mathbb D \ \backslash \ [-1, 0]$ and $\mathbb D$. For example:

- go from $\mathbb D \ \backslash \ [-1, 0]$ to a half-disk using the $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ map
- go from a half-disk to the full disk $\mathbb D$ by following the excellent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882147/find-a-conformal-map-from-semi-disc-onto-unit-disc) here.

Once we have written down a conformal mapping $g : \mathbb D \ \backslash \ [-1, 0] \to \mathbb D$, we can use your knowledge about $Aut(\mathbb D)$ to infer that the biholomorphic maps $\mathbb D \ \backslash \ [-1, 0] \to \mathbb D$ are precisely the functions of the form $f \circ g$, where $f(z) = e^{i\theta} \frac{z - a}{\bar a z - 1}$ for some $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $a \in \mathbb D$.

Your strategy of "restricting the functions $f$ given above" (from your comment) won't work, I'm afraid, because the restrictions of these functions to $\mathbb D \ \backslash \ [-1, 0]$ won't be *surjective* maps to $\mathbb D$.

Comment: I'm a little new to this so I'm not sure if I followed your steps of construction correctly:
We have a $f_1(z)=\sqrt{z}$ mapping the considered area to the half disk. Then we have a $f_2(z)=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ mapping the half disk on the full disk (because $\pm 1$ are the points of intersection) and finally the $f_3(z)=e^{i\theta}\frac{z-a}{\bar{a}z-1}$, so $f_1\circ f_2\circ f_3$ in total.

Comment: @user424862 In the link that I posted, the map from the half-disk to the full-disk was $ z \mapsto -i \frac{z^2 - 2z  + 1}{z^2 + 2z + 1}$, not $\frac{z - 1}{z + 1}$. You should double-check that all the minus signs, factors of $i$, etc. are correct though, rather than taking this on trust. Also, the final answer should be $f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1$.