# Conformal map to unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

I'm trying to find a conformal map from $ G = \{z ∈ C : |z − i| < √ 2 $ and $ |z + i| > √ 2\} $ to the open unit disc. This is what I've tried so far:

I know that we can't have a mobius transformation as the disc has a boundary of one circline and $G$ has a boundary of two.

So I tried to use $f(z) = \frac{z-\alpha}{z-\beta}$, where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the intersection points of the two circles as a first step and I'm not sure what this maps $G$ to and where to go from here.

Comment: The two circular arcs are mapped to straight half-lines from $0$ to $\infty$. Find out which, and to which of the angular sectors your region is mapped. Do you know how to map an angular sector to the unit disk?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882147/find-a-conformal-map-from-semi-disc-onto-unit-disc) is an abstract duplicates. In particular, Mike Miller's answer covers your situation.